# Javascript. Help scheduling dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am helping a friend in his mini project and at this moment we are standing in the following situation: For example a doctor tells his patient that as of TODAY you have X numbers of consultations, every Wednesday and Friday, how to get the dates of these consultations, assuming that TODAY, it can be any day of the week ???
Thanks

Comment: Please provide the code of your attempt to solve this.

Comment: [Date.prototype.getDay()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) might be helpful

Comment: Please read you own question again. Do you understand what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if that is what you want but you can achieve that, for example, like this.

```js
//get current date
var date = new Date ()

//array with week-day names
var week_days = [
  'Sunday',
  'Monday',
  'Tuesday',
  'Wednesday',
  'Thursday',
  'Friday',
  'Saturday'
];

//your initial variables
var consultations = ['Wednesday', 'Friday'];
var X     = 5;

//loop through X + 1 weeks to find dates and count results
var count = 0
for (var i = 0; i < (X + 1) * 7; i++) {
   
  //get name of date-day
  var week_day = week_days[date.getDay ()];
   
  //check if wanted
  if (consultations.indexOf (week_day) != -1) {
    
    //construct date and output
    var day   = date.getDate ();
    var month = date.getMonth ();
    var year  = date.getFullYear ();
    
    document.write (day + '.' + month + '.' + year);
    document.write ('<br/>');
    
    //increment count
    count++;
    
    //stop if count == X
    if (count == X)
      break;
  
  }

  //increment date
  date.setDate (date.getDate () + 1);
  
}
```

Comment: let me ask you, from 1 to 10 how good are you in Meteor JS ?? When i finish this mini project i will need someone to review the code professionally.